# forwarding responsive email in outlook breaks 100% width tables

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, html-email

So I have used a boiler plate to create the responsive email, and it looks good across devices, save Gmail android, but .. cant win them all.

When I forward the email in Outlook 2007 or 2010, the breaks the table up in segments where the table is declared as 100% width. Have tried wrapping the whole email into a table but does not work. We also don't have a email marketing ESP that can provide us with a forwarding link, so that's out of the question. I would like to fix the code, or if there are any solutions ?

The email is the following

http://dev.hurford-salvi-carr.co.uk/charles/email/blackfriars/blackfriars.html

broken email:
[image: broken forwarded image in outlook]

Comment: First check what was stripped in forwarded email. Have you tried to insert styles inside the table?

Comment: Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, thinks that Microsoft Word is the **ULTIMATE** best HTML renderer, and nothing else exists. Outlook uses Word to render HTML. And emphasis on render, as in turning it into unrecognizable slime.

Comment: I dont think anything is stripped, from what I see it forces gaps between the tables.. but inspection is not possible unless there is some sort of word render emulator out there for IE perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

Try forwarding it to a webmail and use inspect element on your email- you'll see that your code is littered with MSO custom CSS like `mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; mso-para-margin:0in; mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt; mso-pagination:widow-orphan;`

Outlook injects this CSS into any rich-text/html email once you send it. This creates a big mess like the one you're seeing. I suppose you could try making `!important` rules at the top to counteract their MSO CSS on every kind of element you have, but you could also be like everyone else and say there's nothing you can do about forwarded emails. Outlook isn't the only program that makes a mess of forwarded HTML either.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook completely rewrites the HTML using the word rendering engine when you send out. Pretty much once Outlook has its claws on your email, it is now a word doc.

It is literally impossible to send anything responsive through Outlook (It strips out all media queries). Your best bet is a scalable email, but even that comes with huge restrictions (no percent width for images, etc). If you want to send responsive, you need to use a different email client to send out.

I usually recommend sending out through Thunderbird as it has the closest to a 'pure' send since it uses the Mozilla rendering engine when sending/receiving HTML in email. There are still quirks, but it offers many more options than Outlook.

I strongly recommend you get an ESP (Email Service Provider) like MailChimp or Exact Target to send these messages though. Forwarding your received email can remove CAN-SPAM compliance. The opt out, etc will be tied to you and not to that person. So if they click opt out, YOU will no longer get the messages, not them and it will leave no record on who actually clicked it. Plus it will make your analytics all screwy.

If you don't care about responsive, etc use the following link to an Email On Acid guide for Outlook coding and it may help a bit more with the table spacing issues [Outlook Tips](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/tips_and_tricks_outlook_07-13). You need to fill out some info to get it, but it is a good reference for coding for Outlook.